# NHibernate JOIN to temp table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I want to do some work in SQL, populating a temp table, and then JOIN to that temp table using an NHibernate CreateSQLQuery to get my final results. We are on version 1.2.0.4000 of NHibernate and I seem to be having problems accessing a temp table in a later query, even though I'm in the same session (I believe this means I'm in the same SQL Session/Connection as well).  Below is a simplified version of my code

```
public void Work()
{
    SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)Session.Connection;

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
                     {
                         CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                         CommandText = "SELECT ID = 1 INTO #TempTable",
                         Connection = connection,
                     };

    if ( Session.Transaction != null && Session.Transaction.IsActive )
    {
        Session.Transaction.Enlist( command );
    }

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Simplified example, I should have a temp table #TempTable with 1 row containing the values ID = 1

    // trying to fetch a list of Account objects where ID exists in #TempTable.
    // At this point, I get an error "Invalid object name '#TempTable'."
    IList<Account> accounts = Session.CreateSQLQuery(@"
        SELECT *
          FROM Account a
          JOIN #TempTable tt
            ON a.ID = tt.ID")
        .AddEntity("a", typeof(Account))
        .List<Account>();

    // Do some work on accounts list
}
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is NHibernate calling through to in your configuration?

Comment: Could you please explain "...I seem to be having problems accessing a temp table in a later query"?

Comment: I'm creating the temp table in the first query using a SELECT INTO, and an ADO.NET straight SQL using ExecuteNonQUery. In the second query, Using the same connection, I use NHibernate CreateSQLQuery to try to JOIN to the temp table. When I execute the second (NHibernate) query in the code sample above, the JOIN to #TempTable fails with the error message in the comments within the code sample. Even though I'm sharing a connection object, I don't think the queries are running in the same SQL session and the temp table is out of scope.

Comment: sessions get connections on demand, it is not guaranteed to get the same connection back. Except using `sessionFactory.OpenSession(myConnection);` which ties the session to the provided connection.

Comment: I'll give this a try the next time I want to do this. I ended up using a different solution for now.  @Firo do you want to post your comment as an answer? I can accept it once I confirm.

Comment: I gave this a try and it seems to be working. I'll give @Firo a few days to post an answer, or I will post one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sessions get connections on demand, it is not guaranteed to get the same connection back.
There are two possibilities to get the same connection every time:

- using `sessionFactory.OpenSession(myConnection);` which ties the session to the provided connection.
- implement IConnectionProvider which does the pooling of the connections

Option 1 is definitly easier